# How can I restore an entity from the database while keeping my entities database-independent?

Tags: c#, architecture, domain-driven-design, database-design, dapper

### Background

I'm currently working on a project using domain-driven design and [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) as my ORM. The entities are naturally slightly different than the tables in which they are stored (e.g. `_id` is `protected` rather than `public`, collections are read-only, etc.), and I'm struggling to find a good approach for restoring the entities inside my repositories (e.g. mapping the `ID` column value to the `_id` field or populating backing collections) without exposing entity methods for those database-specific details.

That is to say, I don't want to end up having a `SetId(int id)` method inside my entities just to accommodate restoring their non-public `_id`s when queried from the database, but I'm struggling to see where I should put the mapping logic and how I could implement it in a maintainable fashion.

### What I've tried

#### Static `CreateFrom` entity method

I considered making a `CreateFrom` method on my entities to have access to these non-public members, but this could potentially allow creating an invalid entity inside the domain on top of involving implementation details that aren't relevant to the domain.

#### `MapFrom` extension method inside infrastructure

I then figured I could create an extension method that does the same, but inside the infrastructure layer where I actually have to do the mapping. The problem here is that I would need an instance of an entity to 'populate' it using the extension method, and that's confusing.

#### Private constructor and forced mapping

I thought that perhaps I could add a private constructor that can be called with a `CreateEmpty` extension method inside my infrastructure layer, in order to populate it using  `MapFrom`, but this would again allow for invalid entity states to be persisted.

### Using Entity Framework (Core) is *not* an option

I know EF is powerful enough to do the mapping for me, but unfortunately I'm currently limited to Dapper. How did people organise their codebases before things like EF or NHibernate existed?

Comment: whats the essential problem here? dapper cant map to protected fields?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299946/mapping-private-attributes-of-domain-entities-with-dapper-dot-net

Comment: @Ewan thanks, I didn't think to check SO first, but both approaches seem pretty hard to maintain, factory because the entity and the record are tightly coupled, and reflection, well, because it's reflection... That said, I think I'm gonna go with the factory approach, thanks!

Comment: What about having a `SetId` method with scope "internal"? If your repos are in a different assembly, you can use `InternalsVisibleTo` to expose `SetId` to them.

Comment: I’d create an internal constructor to enforce a valid state that includes the Id and expose it with InternalsVisibleTo.

Comment: There is no such thing as "preventing invalid entities from being created". Anyone with the power to write the code to call a constructor also has the power to... well... mess up a lot of things. Instead your goal should be to _configure_ your system such that "invalid entities" will not be created. This often means factory methods. Furthermore, it doesn't matter if an "invalid entity" is created so long as you cannot _do_ anything with it. Validation should be enforced when _doing_ something. This comes with the added benefit that the "context" for when an invariant is enforced is clear.

Comment: @king-side-slide I disagree, constructors can contain validation just like factory methods. There's no point in validating an invalid entity's actions if you could nip all of that in the bud by simply disallowing the invalid entity to exist in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is a combination of both approaches(`CreateFrom` and `MapFrom`). Let me explain.

> but this could potentially allow creating an invalid entity inside the domain

This suggests that your entities are a bit useless. One of the points of DDD is [making illegal states irrepresentable](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-making-illegal-states-unrepresentable/). This means that in order to preserve domain invariants your entities should expose constructor of factory method (`CreateFrom`) and perform all needed validation.

Naturally, this constructor/factory method should not accept your DB entity as a parameter since the domain layer should be the core of your application free from all infrastructure dependencies. This is the reason why on your infrastructure layer you have to have `MapFrom` method that calls constructor/factory method from of your domain level in order to create always valid domain entity.